# Using Selenium with TestNg, TestListenerAdapter is getting tests mixed, the driver seems to be getting shared between test classes

Tags: java, selenium, testng, browser-automation

I am running parallel tests using selenium (selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar) grid with TestNg, kicked off by ant, and using a TestListenerAdapter.  Screenshots are taken in the listener's 'onTestFailure' method.  The problem is that the listener seems to get crossed up about which driver it should be using, and sometimes takes a screenshot of the wrong browser window, or fails altogether if the driver that it thinks it should be using has already quit.

When the tests start, TestNg's @BeforeTest and the TestListenerAdapter's 'onTestStart' methods are running on the same thread, but when the test fails, the TestListenerAdapter's 'onTestFailure' method appears to be running on a separate thread.  It seems like the threads are getting crossed/shared somehow, but I can't figure out why.

Here is some skeleton code, any assistance greatly appreciated.

Base Test Class:

```
public class baseClassTests{

    protected AutomationUtils au;
    protected DriverUtils du;

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({ "selenium.OS", "selenium.browser" })
    public void beforeTest(String OS, String browser) {

        //these call simple private methods to know where to set up the driver
        String port = getPort(OS, browser);
        String host = getHost(OS);

        //make a driver utility object here, this makes a driver
        du = new DriverUtils(browser, host, port);

        //pass this driver utility object to another class of utilities
        //this 'AutomationUtils' class gets a RemoteWebDriver ('driver') by calling driver=du.getDriver();
        //the 'AutomationUtils' class is then the one that does all of the 'driver.findBy...' etc
        au = new AutomationUtils(du);
    }


    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeMethod(Method m, ITestResult tr) {
        du.deleteCookies();
        testNgTestName = m.getName();
        print("Method: "+testNgTestName + "   Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().hashCode());
        //set the attribute of the ITestResult object so we can use the same object in the listener
        tr.setAttribute("du", du);
        tr.setAttribute("au", au);
    }

}
```

Listener class

```
public class AmSimpleTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    private DriverUtils driveU;
    private AutomationUtils AutoU;
    private RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private RemoteWebDriver augmentedDriver;
    private String methodName;
    private String browser;
    private String browserVersion;
    String testClass;




    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult tr) {
        //pick up the correct driver utility object from the test class/method we are in
        driveU = (DriverUtils) tr.getAttribute("du");
        AutoU = (AutomationUtils) tr.getAttribute("au");
        driver = du.getDriver();
        augmentedDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) new Augmenter().augment(driver);
        methodName = tr.getName();
        testClass=tr.getTestClass();  //sort of, I actually parse it up a bit
        browser = driveU.getBrowser();
        browserVersion = driveU.getBrowserVersion();
        print("Method: "+methodName + "   Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
       print("Method: "+tr.getName() + "   Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().hashCode());
        try{
            writeScreenshotFile();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Out.error("Unable to take screen shot");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private String writeScreenshotFile() {
        if (driver != null && driver.getSessionId() != null) {
            File scrShot = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File localPathToScreenShot = new File("/path/to/base/directory/"+testClass+"/"+methodName+".png");
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrShot, localPathToScreenShot);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Out.error("Couldn't write screenshot to file");
            }
            return localPathToScreenShot.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return "Could not get path.";
    }

}
```

DriverUtils class makes/supplies the driver

```
public class DriverUtils {

    private RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private int timeout;
    private String browserVersion;
    private String browser
    private DesiredCapabilities caps;

    public DriverUtils(String browser, String host, String port) {
        String hostUrl = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/wd/hub";
        this.browser=browser;
        //do some stuff here to set capabilties
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hostUrl), caps);
        browserVersion = driver.getCapabilities().getVersion();
    }

    public RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public AmBrowser getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    public String getBrowserVersion() {
        return browserVersion;
    }


    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void deleteCookies(){
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }


}


public class AutomationUtils extends BaseClassUtils {

    public AutomationUtils(DriverUtils driverUtils) {
        //pass it up to the base class utils (this is different than base class tests, above)
        //do this so the driver can be accessed by other utility classes as well
        super(driverUtils);
    }

    //All sorts of methods here to find elements, login, blah blah everything that is done with a driver object
}


public class BaseClassUtils { //this is a different class than BaseClassTests

    //make the driver a protected object so all utility classes can access as nec.
    protected final RemoteWebDriver driver;

    public BaseClassUtils(DriverUtils driverUtils) {
         driver = driverUtils.getDriver();
    }

}
```

Tests are run via ant.

```
<suite name="Dev2 for debugging" parallel="tests" thread-count="10">-- tests here </suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering this for a while, I came to the conclusion that there were two things that seemed to help tremendously.

1. eliminate the listener, and take all screenshots in the `@AfterMethod`
2. Move the `@Before/After Method/Test methods` into the child classes, but simply call methods in the parent to do all the work.

Another thing I noticed is that for #2, TestNG is supposed to run the parent `@Before` methods then the child `@Before` methods; and then at the end run the child '@After' methods and then the parent `@After` methods.
I ran a series of simple tests, I found that all before/after methods were not being run, so for the few cases where I was using `@Before` and `@After` methods in both parent and child, I consolidated.

Things seem to run much better now, the driver does not get confused, and screenshots are being attached to the correct browser/test.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ThreadLocal for RemoteWebDriver so it can handle parallel runs:

```
public class DriverUtils {
    private static ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<~>();
    private int timeout;
    private String browserVersion;
    private String browser
    private DesiredCapabilities caps;

    public DriverUtils(String browser, String host, String port) {
        String hostUrl = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/wd/hub";
        this.browser=browser;
        //do some stuff here to set capabilties
        driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hostUrl), caps));
        browserVersion = getDriver().getCapabilities().getVersion();
    }

    public RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
    }

    public AmBrowser getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    public String getBrowserVersion() {
        return browserVersion;
    }


    public void quitDriver() {
        getDriver().quit();
    }

    public void deleteCookies(){
        getDriver().manage().deleteAllCookies();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't seem to do the trick.  What seems to happen is that the '@BeforeTest' (beforeTest) method seems to start multiple test classes on the same thread, and havoc ensues.  When I logged the thread in '@BeforeTest' (beforeTest), for 3 test classes, it seemed to start only using 2 threads...   TRACE: Starting beforeTest for AcceptanceTests.ErrorReportingTests on thread:  1151820366  TRACE: Starting beforeTest for AcceptanceTests.PopupTests on thread:  1227297304 TRACE: Starting beforeTest for AcceptanceTests.CalendarPageTests on thread:  1227297304

Comment: In addition to the ThreadLocal change which is definitely needed for parallel runs with TestNg, try making the RemoteWebDriver in BaseClassUtils non-final (protected RemoteWebDriver driver;) and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried that thanks, but same problem.  The issue seems to be that the '@BeforeTest' beforeTest method is starting two test classes on the same thread.  Once two classes are running on the same thread, I'm hosed, no amount of anything will keep the drivers separate.  I can't figure out why the test classes don't start on separate threads.

Comment: That is definitely weird. Unfortunately, I can't really offer any more suggestions without seeing an example class that is extending BaseClassTests. Those child classes should have their own BeforeTest and BeforeMethod annotated methods that depend on the BaseClassTests methods. TestNg documentation isn't that great, I know, but there is an [example](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations).

Comment: In my case, the BaseTestClass does everything that is needed in the BeforeTest and BeforeMethod methods, so I don't need them in the child classes.  There is nothing special in the test code, it just uses the AutomationUtils ('au') object made in BaseClassTests.  Very strange that two test classes start on the same thread.

Comment: You mentioned running this on Selenium Grid. I don't know if you're running the grid locally or out on a remote server, but have you made sure that you can have more than one instance of a browser running on that grid? For example, if you have three tests set up in the testng.xml, and two are set two execute on chrome, they will most likely share the same thread if the grid can't run more than one instance of chrome.